# Problema al descargar excel en PhpSpreadSheet

Tags: php, laravel, phpspreadsheet

Estoy usando **Laravel 9** y **Phpspreadsheet**, pero al generar el excel, no descarga y sale simbolos raros en la vista previa del navegador al realizar la petición de descarga del excel.

Adjunto imagen del navegador
[image]

Este es mi codigo para generar el excel. Hay alguna otra forma de descargar el excel sin el **save('php://output')**

```
   public function generarTareaMesxCartera($proveedorId, $carteraId)
   {
      $message = '';
      $estado = 1;
      $userId = auth()->user()['id'];
      $success = false;
      ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
      set_time_limit(1800);
      
      $output = array(); $success = false;
      $allTareas = ReportesRepository::getTareasPorCartera($carteraId);

      if($allTareas){
         $message='success';
         $objPHPExcel = new Spreadsheet();

         $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
         ->setCellValue('A1', 'DNI CLIENTE')
         ->setCellValue('B1', 'NOMBRE CLIENTE')
         ->setCellValue('C1', 'FECHA CREADO')
         ->setCellValue('D1', 'FECHA TAREA')
         ->setCellValue('E1', 'OBSERVACION')
         ->setCellValue('F1', 'AGENTE')
         ->setCellValue('G1', 'ESTADO');

         $i = 2;
         foreach ($allTareas as $tarea) {
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueExplicit('A'.$i, (string)$tarea['id_cliente'], DataType::TYPE_STRING);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B' . $i, (string)$tarea['nombres']);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$i, $tarea['fecha_reg']);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$i, $tarea['fecha_tarea']);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueExplicit('E'.$i, (string)$tarea['tarea'], DataType::TYPE_STRING);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueExplicit('F'.$i, (string)$tarea['id_usuario'], DataType::TYPE_STRING);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueExplicit('F'.$i, (string)$tarea['username'], DataType::TYPE_STRING);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueExplicit('G'.$i, ($tarea['id_estado']=1) ? 'Activo':'Gestionado', DataType::TYPE_STRING);
            ++$i;
         }

         $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Tareas del mes');
         $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
         $objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT);
         header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
         header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="tareas_mes.xlsx"');
         header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
         // ob_clean();
         $objWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Xlsx');
         $objWriter->save('php://output');
         exit;
         // return array('message'=>$message,  'reporte'=>'');
      }
      
   }
```

La ruta para llamar al controlador **(generarTareaMesxCartera)**

```
   Route::post('/descargar-tareas-cartera/{proveedor}/{cartera}',[reportesController::class, 'generarTareaMesxCartera']);
```

Para utilizar el api del controlador **(generarTareaMesxCartera)**,

archivo **fullStore.js**

```
export function DescargarTareasxMes(proveedor, cartera){
   reloadData();
   return axios.post("/reportes/file/descargar-tareas-cartera/"+proveedor+'/'+cartera);
}
```

Ultimo llamo al api funcion para usarlo en vuejs y genere el excel

```
import { DescargarTareasxMes } from "@/helpers/fullStore";
getGenerar: function () {
    this.v$.id_proveedor.$validate();
    this.v$.id_cartera.$validate();

    if(this.v$.id_proveedor.$error || this.v$.id_cartera.$error){
     console.log('error');
    }
    else{
     console.log('success');
     DescargarTareasxMes(this.id_proveedor, this.id_cartera)
    }
},
```

Comment: Prueba agregar esto: `ob_end_clean();` justo antes de esta línea: `$objWriter->save('php://output');`

Comment: sigue saliendo los mismos símbolos, no descarga

Comment: ¿Y así: **`ob_end_clean(); return $objWriter->save('php://output');`** Puede que Laravel, o tu propio código, tengan salida por pantalla que estaría interviniendo en el flujo, dañando la generación del archivo. ¿Tienes bien controladas las salidas por pantalla?

Comment: igual no genera el excel; laravel uso en el back y front vue.js, el controlador es la misma funcion que genera el excel.

Comment: Pero, ¿qué más hay donde llamas a `Route::post('/descargar-tareas-cartera/{proveedor}/{cartera}',[reportesController::class, 'generarTareaMesxCartera']);`? Pulsa en [edit] y pon ese contexto completo si es posible.

Comment: ok ya actualice el codigo

Comment: Pues no sé. Convendría revisar el log de errores en el servidor para comprender que es lo que está fallando.

Answer (score 0):

al vueJs, hay dos maneras de hacerlo, una es usando la libreria [js-file-download](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-file-download)
quedando mas o menos de esta manera

```
fileDownload(DescargarTareasxMes(this.id_proveedor, this.id_cartera), "Reports.xlsx");
```

la otra manera sin usar libreria, yo uso esta con Javascript y me funciona

```
      function Descarga(proveedorId, carteraId) {
        window.location.replace('<?php echo base_url('TuController/generarTareaMesxCartera/'); ?>' + proveedorId+ '/' + carteraId);

  }
```